# Why does my db query return zero(no data) in the required coloumns

Tags: mysql

im trying to write a database query to populate two coloumns of a custom table of myn by using three other tables in the same db, but currently those coloumns return nothing, i will provide tables and my query below!!! can any body solve this problem

table_17

```
trackID MyID    Rid     panelID timestamp           useragent_browser   useragent_OS
1       17      123     25      2014-04-29 10:02:01 Default Browser     unknown NULL
2       17      123     25      2014-04-30 05:11:01 Default Browser     unknown NULL
3       17      123     25      2014-05-15 06:44:02 Default Browser     unknown NULL
4       17      59595   25      2014-10-06 07:50:30 Default Browser     unknown 0
5       17      59595   25      2014-10-06 07:51:29 NULL    NULL        0
6       17      59595   25      2014-10-06 07:54:51 NULL    NULL        0
7       17      789     25      2014-10-07 10:20:29 Default Browser     unknown 0
8       17      789     25      2014-10-07 10:23:48 Default Browser     unknown 0
9       17      1881    25      2014-10-27 05:16:11 NULL    NULL        0
10      17      188     25      2014-10-27 05:18:29 NULL    NULL        0
```

projects

```
MyID    projectname     accountID   creationdate        status  launchdate      closedate       total_impr
1       Virgo mobile        1       2010-07-07 09:09:09 3   2010-08-18 09:23:51 2011-11-18 19:38:41 1999
2       sys test            1       2010-06-05 09:12:35 3   2010-06-16 09:10:33 2010-06-30 11:23:55 2
16      test2               1       2010-08-16 14:12:50 1   NULL            NULL            0
7       testproject         1       2010-08-24 14:44:40 2   2014-03-21 22:55:46 NULL            27
18      system2             1       2010-09-21 13:57:46 2   2010-09-21 12:03:23 NULL            51529
19      Holidayland         1       2010-09-30 08:36:55 2   2010-10-03 09:23:55 NULL            6246491
20      thor_test           1       2010-11-17 17:41:11 2   2014-07-17 10:43:53 NULL            0
21      cima                1       2011-02-14 19:13:32 2   2014-07-17 05:07:40 NULL            0
```

my query

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO custom_table (`useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`,`MyID`,`timestamp`,`projectname`)
SELECT `useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`, 'b.timestamp', 'b.MyID',`projectname`
FROM $table a, projects b
WHERE a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND a.MyID = b.MyID") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

The result i get from the query

```
trackID projectname MyID    Rid     panelID timestamp       useragent_browser   useragent_Os

1       testproject 0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 NULL    NULL        NULL
2       testproject 0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 NULL    NULL        NULL
4       Test168-150 0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 Chrome  Win7        NULL
5       Test168-150 0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 Chrome  Win7        NULL
6       Test168-150 0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 Default Browser     unknown NULL
7       Test-155    0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 Default Browser     unknown NULL
8       Test-155    0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 Default Browser     unknown NULL
9       Test-155    0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 Default Browser     unknown NULL
10      Test-155    0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 Default Browser     unknown NULL
14      test155     0       NULL    25  0000-00-00 00:00:00 Default Browser     unknown NULL
```

The columns which i need to populate **Myid** and **timestamp** is zero.. can anybody help me to populate those two correctly

Edit: organized query for readability above

Comment: still the error persists!!! can anybody provide some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing them incorrectly (as strings) and you have them reversed.

In the INSERT you have:

```
`MyID`,`timestamp`
```

In the SELECT you have:

```
'b.timestamp', 'b.MyID'
```

It should be:

```
`b.MyID`, `b.timestamp`
```

Therefore you are not using quotes, so they are not evaluated as strings and they are in the correct order.

Comment: it gives an errorUnknown column 'b.timestamp' in 'field list'

Comment: Because timestamp doesn't exist in the projects table and you assigned projects as b.  What date are you trying to use?  Should it be `a.timestamp`?

Comment: yeah that was part of the problem, and also the order was wrong. now its working thank you for your co-operation